# About the sums $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{n^2}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{1+x^{2n}}$

Tags: summation, theta-functions

[image]Despite all my efforts trying to crack these, i haven't been able to do so. An approach that i've tried gives me somewhat of an asymptotic approximation, but still fails to produce the values near x=0.

The method i've tried is to express the sum as an integral and then integrate it to obtain it's value but apparently there is something that I can't do or something wrong with it.

If anybody can suggest any ideas or (ideally) solve the problem I'd be very grateful. Thanks in advance.

I'll try to show here what I think i did wrong, maybe then you'll be able to point out where i fail at.

Since the two sums are related, i'll only try to find one of them, the second one. Since:
$$ \int_a^b f(x)dx = \lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n f(a+\frac{b-a}{n}k)\cdot \frac{b-a}{n}$$

I let each term of the sum be $\frac{c^k}{1+c^{2k}}$ so, if $x=a+ \frac{b-a}{n}k$ then $f(x)=\frac{n}{b-a}\cdot \frac{c^{\frac{x-a}{b-a}n}}{1+c^{\frac{x-a}{b-a}2n}}$ therefore: $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{c^k}{1+c^{2k}} = \lim_{n\to \infty} \int_a^b \frac{n}{b-a}\cdot \frac{c^{\frac{x-a}{b-a}n}}{1+c^{\frac{x-a}{b-a}2n}}dx$$ and integrating between a and b I obtain (since c<1 and n tends to infinity):
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{c^k}{1+c^{2k}}=\frac{\pi}{4log(\frac{1}{c})}$$ Therefore $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{n^2} = \frac{\sqrt{1-\frac{\pi}{log(x)}}-1}{2}$$ and as x tends to 1- : $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{n^2} = \frac{\sqrt{1+\frac{\pi}{1-x}}-1}{2}$$

But STILL this only works as an asymptotic function. Obviously there is something wrong with this reasoning. Hope you guys can help me. Thanks a lot again.

*Edit: In the photo i've posted you can see the difference between the graph of the functions.

Comment: For the first, see the Jacobi theta functions :http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiThetaFunctions.html . The second is probably related to the polygamma functions .

Comment: These two are related between them: $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{n^2} = \frac{\sqrt{1+4 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{1+x^{2n}}} -1}{2} $$

Comment: What is your actual question? Seeking a closed form? Proving the above relation? How to compute values for small $|x|$ or for $|x|$ near $1$? Something else?

Comment: My question is computing values for small x, since the ones near 1 are given by the above reasoning, but there is a gap between the graph of the sum and the formula that i've obtained near 0.

Comment: What hinders you from simply using truncated series for small $x$?

Comment: I mean, sure, you're right, but still... A closed exact form would be much nicer wouldn't it? Also finding the mistake in my reasoning would be much more enlightening than just leaving it the way it is. All this comes back to finding an irrational number in the Cantor set. So finding the "exact" analytical solution would be better.

Comment: I've tried to "avoid" the explicit use of such function, (i'd like to find something that could be just plugged into a hand-calculator). But seeing where this is going apparently it may be too much to ask. So maybe i'll just have to accept my faith haha. Still those specific values of x look interesting, do they simplify the closed form significantly or what happens? By the way, thanks a lot for your time, I'm quite a newbie in maths (second year in physics and math so far).

Comment: Oops (deleted comment about values for special $x=\exp(-\pi\sqrt{r})$, those include Gamma function values which are not algebraic). No, that's not a simplification, but another path that makes use of the modular properties of the theta functions. If you do not need that, it's better to regard the theta function as a very useful black box.

Comment: In you methodology, how can $f$ depend on anything other than $x$?  In particular, $f$ cannot depend on the same index, $n$, as used to partition the $x$ axis in the formation of a Riemann sum.  Thus, we don't expect the development to lead to an equality.

Comment: That was something i was not sure about, thanks for pointing that out. Can you think of any other way to make that sum an integral?

Answer (score 0):

Let me first summarize some essential comments before proceeding to an answer.

1. As [JJacquelin](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1646128/#comment3357347_1646128) has hinted,
   $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{n^2} = \frac{\theta_3(0,x)-1}{2}$$
   where $\theta_3(0,x)$ is a
   [Jacobi thetanull](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiThetaFunctions.html)
   $$\theta_3(0,x) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty x^{n^2}\qquad(|x| < 1)$$
   Cf. [DLMF ch. 20 Theta functions](http://dlmf.nist.gov/20) and
   [OEIS A010052](http://oeis.org/A010052).
2. As [you have noted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1646128/#comment3357367_1646128),
   $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{n^2} =
      \frac{\sqrt{1+4 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{1+x^{2n}}}-1}{2}$$
   Consequently,
   $$\begin{align}
      \theta_3(0,x)^2 &= 1 + 4\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{1+x^{2n}} \\
      \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{1+x^{2n}} &= \frac{\theta_3(0,x)^2-1}{4}
      \end{align}$$
   Cf. [OEIS A002654](http://oeis.org/A002654) and
   [OEIS A004018](https://oeis.org/A004018)
   where you can find other representations as well, e.g.
   $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{1+x^{2n}} =
      \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\frac{x^{2k-1}}{1-x^{2k-1}}$$
   which can be obtained by expanding the summand to a power series,
   changing the nesting order of the summation, and unexpanding
   the new inner series.
3. As [Dr. MV](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1646128/#comment3357644_1646128) has pointed out,
   your $f$ is not allowed to depend on the step count $n$ whilst
   approximating the integral.

I'd like to add that the [modular properties of $\theta_3$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/20.7.E32) allow you to convert between
values at small $|x|$ and values at $|x|$ near $1$:
$$\theta_3\!\left(0,\exp(-\pi/y)\right)
    = \sqrt{y}\,\theta_3\!\left(0,\exp(-\pi y)\right)
    \qquad(\Re y > 0)\tag{*}$$
Note that the associated *lattice parameter* (period ratio) is
$\tau=\mathrm{i}y$ here.

**To answer your question:**
For computation of $\theta_3(0,x)$ at nonnegative $x$, the
[DLMF notes on computation](http://dlmf.nist.gov/20.14) work quite well.
If $|x|\leq\exp(-\pi)$, the series for $\theta_3(0,x)$ converges very quickly.
Otherwise, you can use the transform $(*)$ which recurs to a new value of
$x$ less than $\exp(-\pi)$.

For negative $x$, compute $\theta_3(0,x)$ as $\theta_4(0,-x)$ in a similar
manner, but note that the modular transformation then swaps $\theta_4$ with
$\theta_2$:
$$\theta_4\!\left(0,\exp(-\pi/y)\right)
    = \sqrt{y}\,\theta_2\!\left(0,\exp(-\pi y)\right)
    \qquad(\Re y > 0)$$
For complex nonzero $x$, the above approach must be slightly refined.
Set the lattice parameter $\tau=\frac{\log x}{\pi\mathrm{i}}$.
Since $|x|<1$, we have $\Im\tau>0$.
Now either recursively compute the true two-variable version $\theta_3(z\mid\tau)$
(initially for $z=0$) or the triple
$$T(\tau) = \left(\theta_2(0\mid\tau),\theta_3(0\mid\tau),\theta_4(0\mid\tau)\right)$$
I'll describe the latter approach.
We have the [modular symmetries](http://dlmf.nist.gov/20.7#viii)
$$\begin{align}
T(\tau+1) &= \left(\sqrt{\mathrm{i}}\,\theta_2(0\mid\tau),
\theta_4(0\mid\tau),\theta_3(0\mid\tau)\right) \tag{T}\\
T(-1/\tau) &= \sqrt{-\mathrm{i}\tau}
\left(\theta_4(0\mid\tau),\theta_3(0\mid\tau),\theta_2(0\mid\tau)\right)
\tag{J}
\end{align}$$
If $\Im\tau$ is greater than some threshold, say $\frac{1}{2}$,
then the associated $|x|$ is very small. In that case, use the series
representations for the entries of $T(\tau)$ with suitable truncation.

Otherwise, use (T) to reduce the real part of $\tau$ such that $|\Re\tau|\leq\frac{1}{2}$. Since $\Im\tau$ is bounded here, we also have
$|\tau|<1$, in fact, with the above threshold $|\tau|\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.
Now use (J) to turn to some $|\tau|>1$; the above-proposed threshold gets us
$|\tau|\geq\sqrt{2}$; in particular, $\Im\tau$ at least doubles in that step.
Repeating those recursions gets you quickly to a state where $\Im\tau$
is large enough that you can use the truncated series.