# The sum of A^(x^2)

Tags: summation

Is there a formula for the sum of $A^{x^2}$ If not, can it be approximated somehow?
I tried finding a formula for it using the sum of $A^x$..I tried differentiating $A^x$ with respect to another function to get just $A$ and then $nA$ which is its sum and then found with respect to what function I will integrate $nA$ to get the standard formula for the sum of $A^x$ .

What I mean is that I tried to find the formula for the sum of $A^x$ by differentiating it with respect to some function to reduce it into a form I can sum and then I integrate the sum of the function I get from differentation with respect to another function such that the result is the sum of the series I wanted to sum which is $A^x$

I Tried doing the same with $A^{x^2}$ so I diffrentiated it with respect to some function to get $A^x$ and then I integrated the sum of $A^x$  with respect to the same function that turned the sum $nA$ into the formula for the sum of $A^x$ but I ended up with an integral that can't be written in closed form..sorry for the ambiguity

I tried many many different methods but none worked.

Comment: I don't quite understand what exactly you're calculating. What are you summing over? What is $A$?

Comment: It's any constant number..like that in a geometric series of the form BA^(n - 1)

Comment: And I'm summing over "n" which is the number of terms I want to add

Comment: Do you mean you're looking for a formula for $\sum_{x=1}^n A^{x^2}$ or something?

Comment: You really need to use sigma notation if you want to be understood.

Comment: Sorry ..I don't know how to use mathjax and I'm on the phone so it's difficult.I tried to avoid using any symbols in the question

Comment: Sorry, but I'm on a very old phone and I try to avoid all the symbols and all the letters too, so I can't type my answer for you.

Comment: Even with an old phone  you can write in black and white the first term of your series, then the second term, then three points, then the last term.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, it seems similar to this: 
[Does the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty b^{k^2}$ have a closed form?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/468187),
[Closed form of a generating function $\sum _{n=1}^\infty x^{n^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1587853),
[About the sums $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{n^2}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{1+x^{2n}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1646128)
Found [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7Bx%3D1%7D%5E%5Cinfty%20A%5E%7Bx%5E2%7D%24&p=1).

Comment: Here I want a formula for the finite sum of $n$ terms of the series $A^{x^2}$ where $A$ is a positive number bigger than one

Answer (score 1):

The wording of the question is very ambiguous. They are some known equations :
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty A^{(n^2)}=\frac12\left(\vartheta_3(0,A)-1 \right)\qquad A<1$$ 
Jacobi theta function, see : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiThetaFunctions.html
$$\int A^{(x^2)}dx=\frac12\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\ln(A)}}\text{ erfi}\left(x\ln(A)\right)+\text{constant}$$
Function erfi , see : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erfi.html

As far as I know, there is no special name for $\sum_{k=1}^n A^{(k^2)}$.

Answer (score 0):

The sum of $$f(n)=\sum_{x=1}^{n} a^{x^{2}}$$ is $$a_1+...+a_n^{n^{2}}$$

Basically, the formula for the $n$th term of the series is one with $n$ terms and each exponent is the $n$th perfect square. Example:

$$f(10) = a^{100}+a^{81}+a^{64}+a^{49}+a^{36}+a^{25}+a^{16}+a^9+a^4+a$$

Comment: How do we know if there is a formula or not? I'm not saying you're wrong..just asking